# Speed up real time from Chrono for simulation purposes

Tags: c++, time, simulation, c++-chrono

Is there a way to speed up the clock in `chrono` for simulation/testing purposes? I have a large project that measures the time from `chrono::system_clock::now()` and uses milliseconds since Epoch to compare internally how long time has passed.

Changing all checks, constants, and limits to a factor is not really viable, unfortunately.

Edit to add: The clock is ofcourse mocked in tests to set a specific time. I want to achieve the same behaviour but sped up by a factor. I dont know how to achieve this since it would require some connection to the real time

Comment: mock your own clock...

Comment: Why don't you multiply by a coefficient your real time measures ? Then you can stretch in any direction your time.

Comment: @Soleil, because that would require hundreds of changes and missing one would be devastating. Also having all checks as "if(now - then > 1.0 * timeFactor)" is a  bit distracting

Comment: @sljdhl This is a completely different problem. You want to use an interface and behind a class or another that implement the interface, so you can switch from regular measures to stretched measures. And you want to (unit) test both classes. I do not think it makes sense to use directly `chrono::system_clock` in any engineering projects. I like to use a class and inside a `map<string, timer>` and the class `timer` provides `start`, `stop`, `elapsed`.

Comment: Thanks @Soleil, ill explain a bit more. Im not directly using chrono, its behind an interface which is mocked in unit tests, however without any real aspect of time passing. What Im having trouble with is grasping the aspect of appearing time passing quicker. But as you have said I should create a timer class that simply multiplies the timeout value in the mocked versions

Comment: @sljdhl About simulations, usually in physics we use a simulated time, not actual time measured by a timewatcher. Real time can also be problematic with unit tests, since CPU load and execution speed can change. So about simulated time, you need to set how the simulated time is passing. For instance you may have an infinite loop and at each step the system state is updated, you can use a `long long unsigned int`  that you increment each step. You also can have a 3rd time: simulated real time, it is related to temperature.